Do I really have to configure my Mail.app accounts manually in all my devices?
I have configured all my email accounts (about 10 smtp/pop accounts on different servers) on my Mac.
I mean the accounts themselves, like their name, servers, ports, etc.
These accounts are not synced to my iOS devices.
Do I have to manually configure it on all devices because Apple did not provide a sync mechanism through iCloud?

Have one master account that they all feed to, then you only have one to configure.

I last attempted this before macOS had similar system settings to iOS so then it was clearly different preference domains for internet accounts. Now things are much closer but I believe you can only sync stored credentials in keychain, not account existence and secrets. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7840625

Are you entering them in Internet Accounts - system preferences  or Mail app settings on your Mac ?

yes @bmike. I have 12 mail accounts configured. I had to add the twelve to all my four devices. Pathetic.

I believe you are correct and at best keychain entries to store secrets will sync via iCloud but not the configuration itself.
MDM mail payloads are the only configuration mechanism I see to accomplish this for macOS and iPadOS and iOS.
Implementing that and secrets (password) sync via iCloud would get you most of the way to automating this.
This lack of sync is covered in this 2012 question before MDM was a thing, so an updated post seems timely.

Without an MDM solution, can you do the equivalent by creating profiles in Apple Configurator which can then be applied on each device?

I don’t see why not @Gilby since the mail payload is flexible in that it works with user enrollment, device enrollment and automated device enrollment and Apple will sign profiles from that app. I (and I believe Apple too) consider(s) Configurator an MDM solution. “These files can be created by an MDM solution or Apple Configurator for Mac, or they can be created manually.”
